# mysql variable set through iteration for Union

Tags: mysql, variables

I have a table of products that I need to upload in a specific format. the products are in sets by similar base_name. I created this UNION query to organize the rows the way it needs to be.

```
SELECT 'Product' as 'Item Type', '' as 'Product ID', base_name as 'Product Name', 'P' as 'Product_Type', mfid as 'Product Code/SKU', manufacturer as 'Brand Name', imap_price as 'Price' from 3d_cart_worksheet where base_name='Jasmine Pendant' group by base_name
UNION
SELECT 'SKU' as 'Item Type', '' as 'Product ID', concat(concat('[S]Finish=', finish), ',',concat('[S]Lamp Type=', lamp_type)) as 'Product Name', '' as 'Product_Type', mfid as 'Product Code/SKU', '' as 'Brand Name', '' as 'Price' from 3d_cart_worksheet where base_name='Jasmine Pendant'
UNION
SELECT 'RULE' as 'Item Type', '' as 'Product ID', concat(concat('[S]Finish=', finish), ',',concat('[S]Lamp Type=', lamp_type)) as 'Product Name', '' as 'Product_Type', mfid as 'Product Code/SKU', '' as 'Brand Name', concat('[FIXED]',imap_price) as 'Price' from 3d_cart_worksheet where base_name='Jasmine Pendant';
```

This works perfectly. What I can't figure out is how to run this over the entire list of products. This code only works for one. How do I iterate through so that it will run this union set when it encounters a new base_name? Do I use a variable? how would I change the variable value to the next new product name? Is there a for each that can be applied?

Thank you

Comment: You can use a MySQL Procedure and define a cursor for all products and go about looping this by passing each product into a variable, but why not just add where base_name in (select prod_name from products ?) in all 3 queries ?

Comment: Tried that, but it runs each query over all the base_names. I need to keep appending the results in groups that have the same base_name.